# Help me to fixe the errors in my code

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

This code does not give me the expected plot, so please help me.

```
t = 1; 
x = 0.1; 
a = 0.3; 
b = 0.5; 
d = 1; 
ϕ = π/3; 
Pr = 1; 
Ec = 0.1; 
Gr = 0.5; 
Gm = 0.5; 
k1 = 1; 
λ1 = 0.5; 
h1 = -1 - k1*x - a*Sin[2*π*(x - t) + ϕ]; 
h2 = 1 + k1*x + b*Sin[2*π*(x - t)];

sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {(1/(1 + λ1)) w''''[y] + Gr*θ'[y] + Gm Φ'[y] - M^2*w''[y] == 0, 
     θ''[y] + Br ((1/(1 + λ1))*(w''[y])^2 + M^2*(w'[y])^2) + r*Nb*θ'[y]*Φ'[y] + Pr*Nt*(θ'[y])^2 == 0, 
     Φ''[y] + (Nt/Nb)*(θ''[y]) == 0, 
     w[h2] == 0, w[h1] == 0, w'[h2] == 0, w'[h1] == 0, 
     θ[h2] == 1, θ[h1] == 0, 
     Φ[h2] == 1, Φ[h1] == 0}, 
    {w, θ, Φ}, {y, h1, h2}];

v1 = sol /. {M -> 0.5, Nb -> 0.1, Nt -> 0.2, Br -> 1}; 
v2 = sol /. {M -> 0.5, Nb -> 0.6, Nt -> 0.2, Br -> 1}; 
v3 = sol /. {M -> 0.5, Nb -> 1, Nt -> 0.2, Br -> 1};

Plot[θ[y] /. {v1, v2, v3}, {y, h1, h2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"y", "θ"}, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"M\[Rule]0.3", "M\[Rule]0.4", "M\[Rule]0.5"}]]
```

Comment: 1) Please make the code more readable 2) Please describe what the right graph _should_ be, what elements are you expecting to be there that are not?

Comment: `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` so you should use `Evaluate` with its first argument: `Plot[Evaluate[\[Theta][y] /. {v1, v2, v3}], {y, h1, h2}, ... ]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `M, Nb, Nt, Br` before you try to use `NDSolve`. Here is an edit of your code that works:

```
t = 1; 
x = 0.1; 
a = 0.3; 
b = 0.5; 
d = 1; 
ϕ = π/3; 
Pr = 1; 
Ec = 0.1; 
Gr = 0.5; 
Gm = 0.5; 
k1 = 1; 
λ1 = 0.5; 
h1 = -1 - k1*x - a*Sin[2*π*(x - t) + ϕ]; 
h2 = 1 + k1*x + b*Sin[2*π*(x - t)];

M = .5;
Nb = .1;
Nt = .2;
Br = 1;

{v1, v2, v3} = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {(1/(1 + λ1)) w''''[y] + Gr*θ'[y] + Gm Φ'[y] - M^2*w''[y] == 0, 
     θ''[y] + Br ((1/(1 + λ1))*(w''[y])^2 + M^2*(w'[y])^2) + Pr*Nb*θ'[y]*Φ'[y] + Pr*Nt*(θ'[y])^2 == 0, 
     Φ''[y] + (Nt/Nb)*(θ''[y]) == 0, 
     w[h2] == 0, w[h1] == 0, w'[h2] == 0, w'[h1] == 0, 
     θ[h2] == 1, θ[h1] == 0, 
     Φ[h2] == 1, Φ[h1] == 0}, 
    {w, θ, Φ}, {y, h1, h2}];

Plot[{v1[y], v2[y], v3[y]}, {y, h1, h2},
  AxesLabel -> {"y", "θ"},
  PlotLabel -> "M\[Rule]0.5\n", 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"w", "θ", "Φ"}]]
```

[image: plot]